# Alternatives to MySQL Partitioning, so we can have a Unique Index

Tags: mysql, partitioning, unique-constraint

I have a DBA vs Developer Issue here, and am wondering if there are any alternatives to partitioning that I can employ here.

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tracking` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `SourceName` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SourceId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`Created`),
  KEY `Cust_Source`(`CustId`,`SourceName`,`SourceId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( TO_DAYS(Created))
(PARTITION `201903` VALUES LESS THAN (737515) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `201904` VALUES LESS THAN (737545) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `201905` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

As you can see, I like to partition my tables, as we only ever keep 2 months data in the live system, and this way I can automatically `DROP` the oldest partition each month.

However, my developer has asked if I can change the `Cust_Source` Index to be a `UNIQUE` Index, to prevent duplicate data being added by mistake. But so doing means I need to lose the partitioning. As:

```
"Error Code: 1503. A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function"
```

And of course, if I include the `created` field in the Index, we could get Duplicate data, created at different times.

Any suggestions?

This needs to work on MySQL 5.5 and 5.7 (although we'll be retiring 5.5 soon, hopefully).

Comment: How many rows do you expect in the table?

Comment: probably a few thousand per day once it goes live, and that will increase over the next few years.

Answer (score 1):

- Since you won't have even a million rows in the table, don't bother to `PARTITION` it.  Then you won't have any trouble with the `UNIQUEness` constraint.
- Change the indexing:

Plan A:

```
PRIMARY KEY(Id),   -- notice: `Created` was removed
INDEX(Created),    -- for purging
UNIQUE(`CustId`,`SourceName`,`SourceId`)  -- as desired
```

Plan B (this assumes you have no real use for `id`):

```
PRIMARY KEY(`CustId`,`SourceName`,`SourceId`)  -- Unique
INDEX(Created)    -- for purging
```

- Purge daily, not monthly.  This is because `DELETE` is much slower than `DROP PARTITION`.  If you still run into performance troubles:  Using Plan B, write a loop to delete the rows for each CustId one at a time.

(I prefer Plan B for your situation.)

(My comments apply to all versions.)

Usually, *each* partition has 4M-7M of "free" space.  Hence a partitioned table is inherently bigger than the non-partitioned equivalent.

Comment: Plan B with a loop is what we do with our older tables which are much bigger, but we then need to optimise these twice a year to free up space which is a real pain. The idea of partitioning is to avoid the need to do the optimising down the line, if this table suddenly starts growing.

Comment: @IGGt - `OPTIMIZE` for space?  Or for speed?  (It is rare that you can get much of either with InnoDB.)

Comment: space. When we did this last, we regained about 400GB space (1.3 TB database initially, down to 900GB afterwards.

Comment: @IGGt - Huh?  The table you describe is under 1GB (a "few thousand a day" for "two months").  That won't be 900GB.  Please fix whichever.  If it is the larger value, I will change my advice.

Comment: Sorry, this table / app feature is still in development, and a few thousand a day is an estimate of what we expect when it is released. The size of 1.3TB is for the whole database, which has some much larger tables. The idea is to get the design right from day 1 so that in a few years time, when this table 'may' be a lot bigger we aren't trying to re-engineer a  table with many millions of rows. (which is where we are now with the older part of the system).

Comment: @IGGt - There are multiple reasons why `OPTIMIZE` may help.  The one table in this Question _may not_ be representative.  Furthermore, 1.3 -> 0.9 smells like exactly the 'normal' overhead for BTrees; did the space promptly grow back to 1.3 (due to block splits)?  (A BTree gravitates toward 69% full as inserts/updates/deletes occur.)

Comment: @IGGt - A side issue:  The efficient way to `OPTIMIZE` a single partition is via `REORGANIZE`, _not_ `OPTIMIZE`.

Comment: the size does go up again, but I wouldn't call it promptly. We currently go through the 'optimise' routine every couple of years to keep the growth rate down.

Comment: @IGGt - My point is that it will go back to 1.3, then stop there.  It will not continue to grow without an influx of data.

Comment: I agree, if everything else remained the same it would fill back up to 1.3 and go no further. But as the company grows, we are putting more data in than we take out, so that space fills up a little quicker each time, and then we can either optimise again, (but free up less space this time), or let it grow a bit bigger (maybe 1.7TB next time).